# Hide some buttons in Woocommerce Admin edit order pages

Tags: css, wordpress, button, woocommerce, orders

I am going crazy with this, I've been searching all day for a solution for this. I know it should be possible with the `display: none;` css work around, but I just cant get it to work.

**I am trying to remove the "Add Product(s)", "Add fee" and "Add shipping" buttons.**

[image]

Comment: Why you need to remove these buttons from dashboard?

Comment: Don't go crazy, Totte. Web is complex, you can't learn it all in one night, you need smaller steps. Today you need to search for (and learn to) find out what rule is responsible for a property that applies to a DOM node. With that information, you can create a stronger selector than the one applying and yours will prevail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this custom function hooked in **`admin_head`** action hiding some Order buttons:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hidding_some_order_buttons' );
function hidding_some_order_buttons() {
    echo '<style>
        .post-type-shop_order .wc-order-add-item > button.add-order-item,
        .post-type-shop_order .wc-order-add-item > button.add-order-fee,
        .post-type-shop_order .wc-order-add-item > button.add-order-shipping{
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works. you will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hello!

This worked GREAT!

I still dont understand where to look, where did you find the:
.post-type-shop_order .wc-order-add-item >

Also, THANK YOU!

Comment: @TotteForstén Thanks… To find the related classes/ids path to target a specific html tag, you can use your browser developer tools inspector, like right clicking on an element will make appear a contextual menu in which you will find something like "inspect this element"...